# Make datastream from thread readable for all other threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, pthreads, posix

I have to distribute a data stream under clients of a multithreaded server instance, the client threads do only need to read. That means I have a thread from which the data comes and all other threads need to read that data (they do not have to change it anymore) so that they can send the data to the clients.

I tried a thread safe queue (https://blog.chrisd.info/a-simple-thread-safe-queue-for-use-in-multi-threaded-c-applications/) but as soon as I tried it with more than one client only the second or the new one received the data.

How do I solve the problem? Are there any thread safe queues that can be used in multiple threads?

Luick

Comment: If the reading thread is processing the data as fast as the writing thread is producing it then this will happen.  You don't say if this is the case or not.

Comment: ah, I will test that out tomorrow, thank you! (Both reading and producing are equally fast at the moment)

Comment: It depends on your situation but maybe hold the data with a `shared_ptr`. Is it just one block of data that gets replaced every so often? Is it an ongoing stream of data or a fixed set of data that simply needs updating now and then?

Answer (score 2):

As from what you described, the usual queue semantics won't work, since you actually want to pop the elements when all the threads have gotten it, not on the first access. So you have several options:

- Maintain a queue per each client thread, and the producer thread always pushes the data into each of the client threads. By wrapping the data into an `std::shared_ptr` you could reduce memory overhead and create semantics, where the data is destroyed when the last client is done with it.
- Have a single queue but multiple tail pointers for each thread. Although this can get complex in terms of handling the threads as they spawn/terminate. But you haven't stated what the constraints are in your system - is the thread count fixed or dynamic.